# Enterprise CMS Project in PlayFramework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, content-management-system, dotcms

I've been shuffling around the internet to get an Enterprise CMS project developed with Play Framework. I came across [dotCms](http://dotcms.com), its not written in play framework. Hence, i feel its not a good idea. Can you recommend any CMS project developed with Play Framework or any other CMS that can be easily integrated with Play Framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on this [play module](https://www.playframework.com/modules/cms) it seems that there were two other cms-modules `Sematic` and ´Percont´. The page [sematic.fr](http://sematic.fr/) looks pretty unmaintained. And [regarding Percont i found this google entry](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/Xe8BEHjs-5I) pointing to a bitbucket last updated 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [Hippo CMS](http://www.onehippo.org/), you can find a Play Framework Hippo CMS integration module on github. If you do not need enterprise features you can configure Hippo CMS like I describe in this [blog post](http://jannisbloe.blogspot.nl/2016/05/integrating-play-framework-and-hippo-cms.html).

Answer (score -1):

Why not use dotCMS via the REST APIs to pull and push content/widgets and or site chrome into your play framework app?  Simple and OTB.

http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/restapi